# Why I am not getting a value when i call a function within another in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a function that generates a random file name

```
#generate random file names
get_rand_filename() {
  if [ "$ASCIIONLY" == "1" ]; then
    for ((i=0; i<$((MINFILENAMELEN+RANDOM%MAXFILENAMELEN)); i++)) {
      printf \\$(printf '%03o' ${AARR[RANDOM%aarrcount]});
    }
  else
    # no need to escape double quotes for filename
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[ -~]' | tr -d '[$></~:`\\]' | head -c$((MINFILENAMELEN+RANDOM%MAXFILENAMELEN)) #| sed 's/\(["]\)/\\\1/g'
  fi
  printf "%s" $FILEEXT
}
export -f get_rand_filename
```

When I call it from within another function

```
cf(){
              fD=$1
              echo "the target dir recieved is  " $fD

              CFILE="$(get_rand_filename)"
              echo "the file name is "$CFILE
}
export -f cf
```

when I call

```
echo "$targetdir" | xargs -0 sh -c 'cf $1' sh
```

I only get the FILEXT (no random file name)

when I call

```
cf "$targetdir"
```

I get a valid result

I need to be able to handle spaces in the $targetdir and file name string.

Comment: not sure about why `fn` isn't working, but if you want a variable to work with spaces, leave it inside dbl-quotes (why would you do `echo "the filename is "$CFILE` when you can do `echo "filename is $CFILE"`. ? Same with `$fD`. Good luck.

Comment: because I am learning Bash and don't know better

Comment: @Asto: `get_rand_filename` outputs several lines. The last line consists only of $FILEEXT. Why are you outputting the file extension on a separate line?

Comment: Are you exporting `get_rand_filename` as well as `cf`? If that's not the problem, adding `set -x` at the beginning of `cf` would probably clarify what's going on.

Comment: Ok, didn't mean to be harsh. Read [bash bitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) every day for a month and you'll be a guru soon ;-) . Good luck!

Comment: ah, a better formatted Q reveals another issue. Replace `echo "$targetdir" | xargs -0 sh -c 'cf $1' sh` with `echo "$targetdir" | xargs -0 sh -c "cf $1" sh` . Note the change from single quotes to dbl-quotes around your call to `"cf $1"`. AND can't remember what `-c` does. You'll need to call the `sh` in a way that the `cf` function gets loaded. Not sure if `export`ing will work in this case where you are using `xargs`. Maybe @GordonDavisson can comment ;-)? Good luck.

Comment: Finally, we should have mentioned this early on, before posting your code (and when you're having trouble in general), you'll do well to copy/paste your code, with a `#!/bin/bash` as the first line into [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net).

Comment: Nope, another thing. `echo "$targetdir" | xargs...` I don't see the point of using `xargs` . `"$targetdir"` is one value that may contain spaces, correct? Ah, just for testing, ok. But still `xargs` needs a token to substitute for the input received on the stream, so maybe `echo "$targetdir" | xargs -I{} -0 sh -c "cf {}" sh`? But @JohnKugelman is right, `mktemp` is the way to go, unless you doing this strictly as a learning exercise. But if that is the case, you've got too many things going on here (and believe me, I've done the same ;-) , but `printf \\$(printf...` , ?? Anyway, good luck!

Comment: @shellter `{}` isn't needed since the OP has `$1`. Remember, by default `xargs` will append arguments to the listed command, which makes them available as `$1`, `$2`, etc. to the given shell invocation. It's actually safer this way. Embedding `{}` inside the command isn't whitespace-safe.

Comment: @shellter, `sh -c '...{}...'` is not just not whitespace-safe, it's a huge security risk. If one of your arguments is `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`, you want it to be passed safely out-of-band from code.

Comment: @JohnKugelman : thanks for the reminder. Is it that O.P. is using `xargs -0` that means $1 can have spaces in it? Thx!

Comment: @shellter, ...`xargs -0` can pass *any* non-null character, so not just spaces but also newline literals.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Excellent, the best people are now on this problem! I missed that completely. (did you mean `"...{}..."` or can `xargs` sub in `{}` anywhere?). AND yes, I sould have mentioned that `-0` is for null terminated inputs. Tnx!

Comment: So does O.P. want single or dbl-quotes around `cf $1`?

Comment: @shellter, I am not using mktemp because I need to control the characters. The file extension needs to be preserved and I need xargs to do the re-naming faster.

Comment: Ok, well how about `myDir=$(mktemp | tr -dc '[ -~]' | tr -d '[$></~:`\\]'`)`? or something like that? Hm.. except according to JohnK mktemp will have locked a different file name. But does that matter for your case? so for the untested case, `myDir=$(mktemp); myDir=$(printf "%s" $myDir |  tr -dc '[ -~]' | tr -d '[$></~:`\\]')` ? Will probably take some tweaking. Good luck! (note that the comments formatter has consumed a back-tick included in `[$></...]`.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson this is the return of set -x

Comment: We are missing the problem. the random function works just fine when cf is called without xargs, but it does not when cf is called using xargs.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "$targetdir" | xargs -0 sh -c 'cf $1' sh
```

You should invoke `bash` rather than `sh`. Function exporting is a bash feature.

```
$ foo() { echo bar; }
$ export -f foo
$ sh -c 'foo'
sh: 1: foo: not found
$ bash -c 'foo'
bar
```

Also, get rid of the `-0` option since the input isn't NUL-separated. Use `-d'\n'` instead. And quote `"$1"` for robustness.

```
echo "$targetdir" | xargs -d'\n' bash -c 'cf "$1"' bash
```

Actually, you could use `-0` if you change the input format.

```
printf '%s\0' "$targetdir" | xargs -0 bash -c 'cf "$1"' bash
```

---

For what it's worth, [mktemp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) creates random temporary files, and does it safely. It makes sure the file doesn't already exist and then creates it to prevent anybody else from snatching up the name in the split second between the name being generated and it being returned to the caller.

Comment: Out of practice with this stuff. so when `targetdir="/path with/spaces"`, `xargs -d'\n' bash -c 'cf "$1"' bash` will get `"/path with/spaces"`, and not `$1` or `""`? Shell quoting opportunities!! ;-)

Comment: @JohnKugelman, when using the "printf '%s\0' "$targetdir" | xargs -0 bash -c 'cf "$1"' bash, the '%s\0'  is passed as a param to xargs.

Comment: The problem I a trying to resolve is that the  call to CFILE="$(get_rand_filename)" is no happening or returning any values when I use xargs.

Comment: CFILE="$(get_rand_filename)" gets called just fine when I call cf "$targetdir"